# Condition if return true with ajax and php even it is false

Tags: php, ajax

I use ajax to send the form to php, the form works fine however the checkbox is not working correctly with the `if` condition.

The output of `var_dump($check1);` false or true it is working fine and output okay.

The output of  `echo " checked";` all the time is checked even `var_dump($check1);` is false.

Where is my error and why is the output true all of the time?

send_ajax.php

```
<div id="txt">Result</div>
<input type="text" name="in1" id="in1" required="required"/><br>
<input type="text" name="in2" id="in2" required="required"/>
<input type="checkbox"   name="checkbox" id="checkbox"  required="required"/>
<button type="submit" class="" name="up" id="up" >Sign Up</button>
<script>

                $("#up").click(function(){
                    var in1=$("#in1").val();
                    var in2=$("#in2").val();
                   var checkbox1=$('#checkbox').is(':checked');
               //  var checkbox1=$("#checkbox").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'confirm.php',
                        method:'POST',
                        data:{
                            in1:in1,
                            in2:in2,
                            checkbox1:checkbox1
                        },
                        success:  
                         function(data) {
                            $("#txt").html(data);
                        }
                    });
    })

        </script>
```

confirm.php

```
<?php

$in1=$_POST["in1"];
$in2=$_POST["in2"];
$check1=$_POST["checkbox1"];


var_dump($check1);
echo "<br>";
if($check1==true){
    echo " checked";
}
else{
    echo " not checked";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transmission of boolean and check on it serverside can lead to unexpected due to low typing.

What happens if you init your variable this way ?

```
$check1= $_POST["checkbox1"] == 'true' ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using

```
$check1=$_POST["checkbox1"];
```

but there name is checkbox

```
$check1=$_POST["checkbox"];
```

Comment: `checkbox1` is a key in `data`.

Comment: I Think this not correct as checkbox1 is only a variable and can be any name(not related to checkbox).